# A question about recoding multiple factor levels simultaneously in R

Tags: r, factors

Data manipulation is a breeze with the amazing packages like *plyr* and *dplyr*. Recoding factor levels, which could prove to be a daunting task especially for variables that have many levels, could easily be done with these packages. However, it is important for those learning Data Science to understand how the basic R works.

I seek help from R specialists about recoding factors using the base R. My question is about why one notation works while the other doesn’t in R.

I generate a vector with five categories and 300 observations. I convert the vector to a factor and generate the following tabulation.

```
x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 300, replace = TRUE)
x <-factor(x)

> table(x)
a  b  c  d  e  f 
57 58 51 45 45 44 

> table(as.numeric(x))
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
57 58 51 45 45 44
```

Note that by using as.numeric option, I could see the internal level structure for the respective character notation. Let’s say, I would like to recode categories a and f as missing. I can accomplish this with the following code.

```
x[as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)] <- NA
> table(factor(x))
b  c  d  e 
58 51 45 45
```

Where 1 and 6 corresponding to a and f.

Note that I have used the position of the levels rather than the levels themselves to convert the values to missing.

So far so good.

Now let’s assume that I would like to convert categories a and f to grades. The following code, I thought, work, but it didn’t. It returns varying and erroneous answers.

```
# Recode and a and f as grades
x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 300, replace = TRUE)
x <-factor(x)
table(as.numeric(x))
levels(x)[as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)] <- "grades"
table(factor(x))
 a      b      c grades      e      f 
46     46     56     52     42     58
```

However, when I refer to levels explicitly, the script works as intended. See the script below.

```
x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 300, replace = TRUE)
x <-factor(x); table(x)
my.list = c("a", "f")
levels(x)[levels(x) %in% my.list] <- "grades"
table(factor(x)) 
grades      b      c      d      e 
   110     49     40     45     56
```

Hence the question is why one method works and the other doesn’t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve?

Manipulating factors by using `as.numeric()` is not a good idea and you may have surprises. May favorite way is to avoid factors whenever possible (using e.g. `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating data frames and `as.is=TRUE` with `read.csv` and `read.table` -- `as.is` because the opposite is `as.it.is.not`). Manipulating character vectors is much more straightworward and less error prone than any operations with factors, and when a factor is, technically needed, in many cases the analysis functions take care of it -- or if that's not enough, it is often easier to create a factor (with levels) on the fly, with an appropriate ordering and labeling of levels, than to worry about all the confusions related to factors.

So what happens in ..

```
 levels(x)[as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)]
```

`levels(x)` is a character vector with length 6, `as.numeric(x)` is a logical vector with length 300. So you're trying to index a short vector with a much longer logical vector. In such an indexing, the index vector acts like a "switch", TRUE indicating that you want to see an item in this position in the output, and FALSE indicating that you don't. So which elements of `levels(x)` are you asking for? (This will be random, you can make it reproducible with `set.seed` if that matters.)

```
> which(as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6))
 [1]   4   9  10  12  14  16  24  35  37  44  47  52  54  57  58  61  63  69  79  81  82  83
[23]  84  86  87  89  91  92  99 100 103 109 114 121 124 125 129 134 135 138 140 141 143 147
[45] 154 167 178 179 181 187 188 194 201 212 213 214 217 218 219 220 222 232 235 237 239 245
[67] 254 255 258 260 263 265 266 267 275 278 281 286 294 295 296
```

If you want to replace some levels by referring to their numeric equivalent, you don't need `as.numeric` at all:

```
 levels(x)[c(1,6)] <- "grades"

 > levels(x)[c(1,6)] <- "grades"
 > table(x)
 x
 grades      b      c      d      e 
    101     45     46     62     46
```

"a" and "f" have been replaced by "grades" as you wanted. Whereas with "as.numeric" above, you thought of levels 1 and 6, but actually asked only level 4 to be changed. (which level[s] exactly,is up to the RNG and not directly under your control).

Comment: Thank you indeed. Simple and clean. I was overthinking the problem and unnecessarily introduced as.numeric.  Your proposed solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 300, replace = TRUE)
x <-factor(x)
table(as.numeric(x))

# 1  2  3  4  5  6 
#44 55 56 49 48 48
```

Now, when you are trying to change `levels`

```
length(as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)) #gives
#[1] 300
```

whereas

```
length(levels(x)) #is just
#[1] 6
```

Next, when you do

```
as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6) #it returns a vector of length 300
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE.......
```

So now, when you do

```
levels(x)[as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)]
#[1] "d" "e" "f" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA .....
```

with remaining all of them as `NA`s as there are no more `levels` to select from.

So,

```
levels(x)[as.numeric(x) %in% c(1,6)] <- "grades"
```

changes "d", "e" and "f" to "grades"

```
table(x)
#x
# a      b      c grades 
#44     55     56    145
```

but that is not what you intended.

In your second attempt

```
levels(x)[levels(x) %in% my.list]
```

it works because

```
length(levels(x))
#[1] 6
```